# Why can't I save a pointer to a struct to an index of a pointer to an array of pointers?

Tags: c, linux

I've done something similar to this in the past so I'm not sure why when I try to print my pointer to an array of pointers I get a bunch of (null)'s as output.  This is the code I'm speaking of near the bottom of the file:

```
int z = 0;
while (z < 9) {
    printf("%s ", allLines[z]->username);
    z++;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get a directory (either relative or absolute) from the user then change to that directory and open all the text files inside that directory so that I can extract each line from them and store each line inside a records struct.  Please see my code below:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define MAXLINE 256
#define MAXPATHLENGTH 1024
#define MAXRECORDS 10000
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct records {
    char* username;
    char* password;
    char* bloodType;
    char* domainName;
    char* index;
} records;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("You must provide 2 arguments: <./filename> <directory>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char* path = malloc(MAXPATHLENGTH * sizeof(char));
    char* cwd = malloc(MAXPATHLENGTH * sizeof(char));
    FILE* sortedFile;
    FILE* dirEntry;
    DIR* dirp; //pointer to a directory stream  
    struct dirent* dirstructp; //pointer to a dirent structure 
    struct stat buffer;
    records** allLines = malloc(MAXRECORDS * sizeof(records));
    int linesInFile[MAXRECORDS];
    records** files = calloc(MAXRECORDS, sizeof(records)); //pointer to an array of pointers (each of which point to a records struct)
    int totalFiles;

    if ((sortedFile = fopen("sorted.yay", "w+")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        printf("fopen");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //changes the current working directory of the calling process to the directory specified
    if((chdir(argv[1])) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(errno);
    }

    /*copies the pathname of the current working directory to the array pointed to by cwd, which is of length MAXPATHLENGTH*/
    if((path = getcwd(cwd, MAXPATHLENGTH)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(errno);
    }

    //returns a pointer to the directory stream if successful 
    if((dirp = opendir(path)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        printf("opendir");
        exit(errno);
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int l = 0;
    while((dirstructp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL) {

        if ((strncmp(dirstructp->d_name, ".", strlen(".")) != 0) && (strncmp(dirstructp->d_name, "..", strlen("..")) != 0)) {

            if(lstat(dirstructp->d_name, &buffer) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                printf("Bob Saget");
                exit(errno);
            }

            if(S_ISREG(buffer.st_mode)) {

                if ((dirEntry = fopen(dirstructp->d_name, "r")) == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
                    printf("fopen2");
                    exit(errno);
                }   

                char* buf = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));
                while(fgets(buf, MAXLINE, dirEntry)) {                            
                    records* line = malloc(sizeof(records));       
                    int k = 0;         
                    while(k < 5) {                            
                        char* token = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));                
                        token = strsep(&buf,",");                                               
                        switch(k) {                                            
                            case 0:                                                           
                                line->username = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));                                   
                                strncpy(line->username, token, strlen(token));                           
                                break;                                             
                            case 1:                                              
                                line->password = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));            
                                strncpy(line->password, token, strlen(token));                          
                                break;                                             
                            case 2:                                              
                                line->bloodType = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));            
                                strncpy(line->bloodType, token, strlen(token));                      
                                break;                                             
                            case 3:                                                
                                line->domainName = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));           
                                strncpy(line->domainName, token, strlen(token));                
                                break;                                              
                            case 4:    
                                line->index = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));
                                strncpy(line->index, token, strlen(token));         
                                break;                                             
                        }
                        k++;                                                      
                    }                                                         
                    allLines[l] = line;         
                    l++;
                    free(line);                                                                  
                    free(buf);                
                    buf = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));                      
                }                      
                linesInFile[j] = i;
                i = 0;    
                files[j] = allLines;  
                j++;         
                totalFiles = j;
                free(buf);
            } 
        }
    }
    int z = 0;
    while (z < 9) {
        printf("%s ", allLines[z]->username);
        z++;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any error checking for any of your calls to `malloc()`, nor any code that ensures you don't overrun buffers.  The code is so poorly formatted - with lines of code that go *waaayy* off to the right - that it's unreadable.

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't know why it was formatted that badly.  I just used CTRL-k. Definitely isn't that way on my computer. I'll touch it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
records* line = malloc(sizeof(records));
...
line->username = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));
...  
allLines[l] = line;
...  
free(line);
...  
printf("%s ", allLines[z]->username);
```

You free the `allLines[z]` pointer so it is not valid and accessing it is undefined behavior.

1. I suggest you cleanup your code.
2. Also please, next time, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is a *minimal* example needed to reproduce the issue.
3. This is a good time to learn how to debug your programs.
4. `char* token = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));

                       token = strsep(&buf,",");` just leaks memory....
5. What if the line is malformed and `token = strsep(&buf,",");` returns NULL? Your code will do undefined behavior in `strncpy(line->index, token, strlen(token));` and the program will most likely receive sigsegv on linux.
6. `char* buf = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));
               while(fgets(buf, MAXLINE, dirEntry)) {` and `free(buf);

                   buf = malloc(MAXLINE * sizeof(char));`. The free + malloc with the same buffer is just pointless.
7. Please properly indent your code. If your code has more then 3 levels of identation, it's time to create a function. Grab a good read: [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html).
8. All the `strncpy(line->password, token, strlen(token));` are just strange.  Firstly, it's the same as `strcpy(line->password, token)` and second if `strlen(token)` is equal to MAXLINE the output will not be null terminated and secondly if `strlen(token)` is greater then MAXLINE this will invoke undefined behaviour. You should `line->username = malloc((strlen(token) + 1) * sizeof(char)); memcpy(line->username, token, strlen(token) + 1);` or just `line->username = strdup(token);`. Also would be good to `if (line->username == NULL) { handle errors; }`. Or protect against UB with a simple `if (strlen(token) >= MAXLINE) { fprintf(stderr, "token too long!"); abort(); }`. Or you can `strlcpy(line->username, token, MAXLINE)` which will protect against overflow and always null terminate the output. Don't use `strncpy`, it's a bad function.
9. The allocation for `allLines` is invalid. `records** allLines = malloc(MAXRECORDS * sizeof(records));` It should allocate an array of `sizeof(records*)` pointers not records. You can allocate an array `records* allLines = malloc(MAXRECORDS * sizeof(records));` which can probably fix you code with just `allLines[l] = *line;`. But the accesses need to use `.` then `->`, like `printf` needs to be changed with `printf("%s ", allLines[z].username);`
10. Same goes for `records** files = calloc(MAXRECORDS, sizeof(records));` This is a pointer to a pointer to files.
11. The portable and posixly defined macro with probably the same meaning as `MAXPATHLENGTH` is `PATH_MAX` which is defined in `limits.h`
12. `char* path = malloc(MAXPATHLENGTH * sizeof(char));` and `path = getcwd(cwd, MAXPATHLENGTH)` leaks memory(!) and just strange. On success `path == cmd`... I suggest you just want `cmd = get_current_dir_name()`.

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better answer.  I came here with a simple question but you improved my code everywhere.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`records** allLines = malloc(MAXRECORDS * sizeof(records));`

Change it to:

`records** allLines = malloc(MAXRECORDS * sizeof(records*));`

The same goes for the line initializing `records** files`

Also: `files[j] = allLines;` is wrong. You are assigning a double pointer to a single pointer.